# PHP Selecting a specific row

Tags: php, mysql

I have recently been working with PHP but do not know much.

Right now I am trying to get all info from a row. This is what I have so far:

```
$server = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM servers;");
$serverFinal = mysql_fetch_row($server);
```

This is working, but whenever I have more than 1 row in the table it just keeps giving me the first row.
This is the full code:

```
<?php
include "C:/wamp/www/minebook/mysql/info.php";
$db_database    = 'minebook_servers';
mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass);
mysql_select_db($db_database);

    $result = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM servers"));
    $f = 1;
    while ($f <= $result['count']) {

    $server = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM servers;");
    $serverFinal = mysql_fetch_row($server);

    $response = $status->getStatus("$serverFinal[1]", $serverFinal[2]);

        if(!$response) {
    echo '
            <tbody>
                    <tr>
        <td class="mname">'.$serverFinal[0].'</td>
        <td class="mserver">OFFLINE</td>
        <td class="mstatus">OFFLINE</td>
                    </tr>
            </tbody>
         ';
    } else {
    echo '
        <tbody>
                    <tr>
        <td class="mname">
        '.$serverFinal[0].' '.$serverFinal[1].' '.$serverFinal[2].'
        </td>
        <td class="mserver">
        <img class="theadImage" border="0" src="/minebook/pictures/d_helmet.png"         alt="Name" width="22" height="18">
        '.$response['players'].'/'.$response['maxplayers'].'
        <img class="theadImage" border="0" src="/minebook/pictures/grass.png" alt="Name" width="18" height="18">
        '.$response['version'].'
        </td>
        <td class="mstatus">
        ONLINE
        </td>
                    </tr>
        </tbody>
';
                }
    $f++;
    }
        ?>
```

And I know I should be using mysqli. I am switching it all over soon.

Comment: Try using `mysql_fetch_assoc` instead of `mysql_fetch_row`

Comment: Do use `MySQLi_` instead of `MySQL_`, or better yet PDO. `MySQL_` This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future.

Comment: mysql_fetch_assoc makes the $serverFinal[0]'s unusable and throws errors. And also I know about the MySQLi thing, I will be switching it over soon.

Comment: What do you want to get all the rows or just a particular one?

Comment: I am trying to cycle through all rows and echo out there variables(name, ip, port in this case).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are little confused with the database operation. Follow following steps:

1. Query the database and get all your results. (Don't query inside a loop)

   `$server = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM servers");`
2. Now loop through your result and fetch them.

   `while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($server) ){
         //the $row will contain all the data related to this row
    }`

So, you need to do something like this:

```
$server = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM servers"); //query outside the loop
while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($server) ){ //fetch in a loop
   //the $row will contain all the data related to this row
   $response = $status->getStatus("$row['field_name']", $row['field_name']);
   if(!$response) {
     //continue your work
   }
}
```

As a sidenote, `MySQL_*` extension is deprecated and is no longer maintained. Use `PDO` or `MySQLi_*` insetad.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are not looping in your inner SQL statement.

```
 while (($serverFinal = mysql_fetch_row($server)) !== FALSE) {
     // do everything here
 }
```

Comment: I dont see why I would need to use that. All that is saying is to continue the statement if mysql_fetch_row($server) is not false.

Comment: Every time you go one more iteration in your outer loop you execute the inner query which resets the result pointer. That's the reason it always shows only the first result. Instead, you should execute the query only **once**, and loop it until you reach to the end of result set.